# express - stream.pipe(res) - bigger files show error 500

Tags: javascript, express

I'm creating a readStream from google cloud storage file and piping it to res.

It works fine for small files around 3MB on my network. (Instantly downloads)

But when I try to download a larger file around 30MB. It doesn't start any download, just shows ERROR 500. (no error on server side)

```
app.get("/playlist/download/:ID", async (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.ID;

  //setting the right headers
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/zip');
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + 
  playlist.getTitle(id) + ".zip");

  try {
    const file = playlistsBucket.file(`${id}.zip`);
    var meta = await file.getMetadata();
  
    //even tried setting content length
    res.setHeader("Content-Length", meta[0].size);

    if (await file.exists()) {
      var stream = file.createReadStream();
      //piping the file here.
      stream.pipe(res);
    }
    else res.sendStatus(404);
  } catch (err) {   
      console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
}});
```

Comment: I believe that the error is just outside of `try catch` that's why you don't see it.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski The stream opens just fine, code doesn't terminate, nor throws any errors anywhere.

Comment: It returns 500 so it for sure throws somewhere
How do you know what the stream opens?

Comment: logs just under the `stream.pipe(res)` show and `stream.on("drain")` also fires. It even fires hundreds of times, so i'm really confused why it doesn't work.

Comment: What about the code you have in catch? It could throw as well

Comment: Updated it. The code is completely fine. It works for small files all the time. The only issue is with bigger files.